# What's wrong with this DB2 SQL Query?

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT
    getOrgName(BC.ManageOrgID),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT FO.OBJECTNO FROM FLOW_OBJECT FO WHERE FO.ObjectNo=CR.SerialNo) AND NVL(CR.FinallyResult,'') IN ('01','02','03','04','05')) THEN BC.ManageOrgID ELSE NULL END) 
FROM
    BUSINESS_CONTRACT BC,
    CLASSIFY_RECORD CR
WHERE
 CR.ObjectType='BusinessContract'
AND CR.ObjectNo=BC.SerialNo
GROUP BY BC.ManageOrgID, CR.SerialNo, CR.FinallyResult
```

The error message I receive is:

> 11:01:32  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -112, SQL State: 42607]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-112, SQLSTATE=42607, SQLERRMC=SYSIBM.COUNT, DRIVER=3.57.82
>   ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The operand of the column function name (in your case, count) includes a column function, a scalar fullselect, or a subquery." DB2 doesn't allow this.  See the documentation on [SQL112](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0112.htm) for more.

I'm not really sure how to fix your query but perhaps you can try the HAVING clause after GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to rework the query:

```
SELECT
getOrgName( BC.ManageOrgID ),
COUNT( FO.ObjectNo ) AS objectcount
FROM BUSINESS_CONTRACT BC
INNER JOIN CLASSIFY_RECORD CR
    ON CR.ObjectNo = BC.SerialNo
    AND CR.ObjectType = 'BusinessContract'
    AND CR.FinallyResult IN ( '01','02','03','04','05' )
INNER JOIN FLOW_OBJECT FO
    ON FO.ObjectNo = CR.SerialNo
GROUP BY BC.ManageOrgID
;
```